# Need to call NSAutoReleasePool after performSelector:withObject:afterDelay?

Tags: iphone, ios

As title. Do I need to call NSAutoReleasePool after calling  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay?

I think  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: is not on main thread, so it is necessary to add autorelease pool. Is that correct?

ex:

```
[self  performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

-(void) update {
NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init]; // Is it necessary
...
[pool drain];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This method executes the supplied selector **on the same thread/run loop on which you called it**, using an NSTimer scheduled for that actual run loop. You don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The only instance where you'd need to create your own `@autoreleasepool` would be if you were creating and autoreleasing a lot of objects all at once.

In your case your `update` method will be called on the same thread/runloop as you created it, and would fall happily under the main `@autoreleasepool`.

The [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation has some wordy details on the particular methods you're calling.

Comment: "The only instance where you'd need to create your own autoreleasepool would be if you were creating and autoreleasing a lot of objects all at once." - that's wrong. You also need separate autorelease pools for any thread you detach.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's true. The OP is working isn't detaching NSThreads however.